# Windows10 internet connection problems after restarting. No hardware devices connections found

Tags: connection, windows-10, internet-connection

Yesterday was 13th, probably well known virus caused crash of internet connection and Windows 10  functions.  I could not use keyboard and mouse either to restart or to repair Windows10 with advanced options. With installation USB program started but with bugs and no internet  connections was available since no hardware devices found.

Answer (score 0):

The freeware tool cFosICS manages Windows Internet Connection Sharing. It comes with additional commands to fix the Windows 10 bug which may stop Internet Connection Sharing from working after a reboot.

See details here: https://www.cfos.de/en/cfosspeed/cfosics.htm

Answer (score -1):

Try Installation from a DVD .This is Most preferable.Or you can use latest version of RUFUS to boot your Flash Drive.Install the latest version of Windows 10 Pro.

[Goto Here For Download](https://onhax.me/tag/windows-10-all-the-editions-torrents)

Make sure you have internet connectivity to Sign in to Windows Account.
Set the Update off if you have all problems are solved.

Hope it will help !!

Answer (score -1):

I checked status on cmd with configip/all and got answer IP routing is disabled.  So I went to device manager I looked in help how to connect to internet. In Microsoft Management Console/Contents/Get Connected/ there is Connecting to the Internet procedure.
I used Get-NetAdapter. t-NetAdapter: Cannot connect to CIM server error. The service can not be started, either because it is disabled or because another software installation is in progress. Same with Test-Configuration command. The error means: „Cannot connect the computer to the server because of restart pending.

**The simple is to use Microsoft Virtual Agent which will  with your problem question and it will guide it through steps needed to solve problem. It also recommednds cmd commands as referred above. In my case I had to update Windows10 with formed USB key.**